# Invalid escape character syntax error - Ruby

Tags: ruby, url, firefox, uri

Trying to open this chain of URL's using the firefox executable.

And receiving error message (in cmd prompt with Ruby) that I have an invalid escape character syntax error.

I'm not sure where the error is in my system call.

```
search_criteria = ["makers", "makerspaces", "fablabs", "smartlabs"]
names = ["new+york+city", "new+york", "nyc"]

query_strings = names.map do |name|
    "#{name}+#{search_criteria.join('+')}"
end

urls = query_strings.map do |q|
    "google.com/search?q=" + q
end

cmd_line = urls.join(' ')

system("C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe --url #{cmd_line}")
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I don't understand where the error is in my system() call

Comment: BTW, you really should be using the multi-argument version of [`system`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Kernel.html#method-i-system) if you're going to use it at all: `system('c:\Program Files...', '--url', cmd_line)`. Have a look through the Ruby CERT notices and you'll see why you should never ever use the single argument version of `system`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Im not sure in windows.
But you seems to escape backward slash.

```
system("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe --url #{cmd_line}")
```